# Port number to use

Tags: sockets, port

I am developing a c++ socket server for internal purpose and I need to assign a port number for the server. According to this wiki page, the range 49152–65535 used for private or customized services, for temporary purposes, and for automatic allocation of ephemeral ports.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

So would like to understand is it safe to use port number between 49152–65535.

Comment: Provide the port number as parameter with taking a default from that range. Let the sysadmin decide which port finally to use.

Comment: It should be okay if you just pick a random port that isn't less than 1024. If you really want to safe than don't use a port within the range you specify